# How to interpret remote()->transact in AOSP source code

Tags: graphics, rendering, ipc, android-source, android-binder

I'm trying to see what's going on inside of the Surface::dequeueBuffer() function in AOSP, in the Surface.cpp file. I tracked it to IGraphicBufferProducer.cpp, but I get stuck at the line

`status_t result = remote()->transact(DEQUEUE_BUFFER, data, &reply);`

I can't seem to find what exactly remote() is doing. I think it has something to do with Binder IPC, but not sure...does anyone know where I could find the implementation of this?

Comment: Correct, this is a binder transaction. The `remote()` call returns a proxy object ([reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/cf03cf14dc19884585528ba402fda02689bebb01/libs/binder/include/binder/Binder.h#134)), which usually has been received from the service manager. The proxy object holds the necessary information for identifying the process which hosts the binder service. I'm not sure how much detail you want to go into.

Comment: The transaction will go through the kernel (by ioctl'ing the transaction data to `/dev/binder`), and the kernel will forward it to the remote process that is specified by the `IBinder` proxy object. Eventually the transaction will arrive in [`onTransact`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/b13d750d9497f0f3f05955955f34231635ce2931/libs/gui/IGraphicBufferProducer.cpp#786), which then calls the `requestBuffer` of the actual binder service that inherits from `BnGraphicBufferProducer`.

Comment: Small correction to the comment of @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 : When binder transaction is received at `BnGraphicBufferProducer::onTransact`, from the switch-case `dequeueBuffer(...)` function is being invoked.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. You are right, I was in the wrong line of the code there.

Comment: @serviceberry3, program flow goes to [BufferQueueProducer::dequeueBuffer](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/native/libs/gui/BufferQueueProducer.cpp;l=379) `Surface::dequeueBuffer` ⮕ `BpGraphicBufferProducer::dequeueBuffer` ⮕ `BnGraphicBufferProducer::onTransact(DEQUEUE_BUFFER, ...)` ⮕ `BufferQueueProducer::dequeueBuffer` (frameworks/native/libs/gui/BufferQueueProducer.cpp)

Comment: @Lakindu Thanks, that's extremely helpful. Do you know any way to modify those functions (i.e. dequeueBuffer())? I've tried to do so, but I always get errors because my modified version doesn't match the version in IGraphicBufferProducer.hal. Or do you know how to modify the HAL? It seems very fidgety with the hashes and everything...